# Accessing unions in struct

Tags: c++, loops, c++11, struct, unions

Consider following code:

```
struct test1str
{
    int testintstr : 2;
    int testintstr2 : 1;
};

struct test2str
{
    int testintstr : 2;
    int testintstr2 : 1;
};

union test1uni
{
    int testint1;
    test1str str1;
};

union test2uni
{
    int testint2;
    test2str str2;
};

struct finalstruct
{
    test1uni union1;
    test2uni union2;
} finstr;

int* ptr = &finstr.union1.testint1;

finstr.union1.testint1 = 2;
finstr.union2.testint2 = 4;

cout << &finstr.union1 << endl;
cout << &finstr.union2 << endl;
printf("val: %i addr: %x\n", *ptr, ptr);
ptr++;
printf("val: %i addr: %x\n", *ptr, ptr);
```

Is there more appropriate way of accessing values from unions inside example finalstruct? Using code from above example, I could iterate throught all unions inside "finalstruct", and get int that was needed, but is there some other way to do this?

Assume that data size from all structs will be less or equal to the size of variable inside union - structs will be treated as bitfields, and data will be read through union variable.

This will be used only on one type of processor, compiled with one compiller (gcc) and sizes of all structs and unions will be the same (except of finalstruct of course). What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to change different bits easily by using struct (test1str, test2str), and for reading I need to know only what will be final value that these bits will make - for that I will use union (test1uni, test2uni). By packing these unions inside struct (finalstruct), I can easily process all data.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you're trying to do, and why.

Comment: I'm trying to find a better way to access values from unions (like testint1) that are inside struct (finalstruct in this example) in a way that will allow me to iterate through all elements of struct without explicit declaring what I want (like get finstr.union1.testint1 then get finstr.union2.testint2 etc.) - in above example pointer to int was used, but could this be done differently?

Comment: That's not what you're trying to do, that's how you think you should do it

Comment: Now I'm not sure if I understand you. Are you saying that I'm doing something in a wrong way? If so, then how it should be done?

Comment: No, I'm trying to get you to tell us _what you're trying to do_. What is your goal? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I added more explanation, and about UB - isn't true that each element of struct will be placed next to each other in memory?

Comment: Computer programs are not just about layout in memory.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> ptr++
> ```

`ptr` does not point to an element of an array, so after you increment it, it is no longer valid - even if there happens to be another object in that address. When you indirect through it, the behaviour of the program is undefined.

What you really need to iterate members of a class is language feature called "reflection". C++ has very limited support for reflection. You could store references to the members in an array, and iterate the array. Note that since we cannot have arrays of references, we need to wrap them, and in case of `printf`, explicitly convert the wrapper back:

```
std::array members {
    std::ref(finstr.union1.testint1),
    std::ref(finstr.union2.testint2),
};
auto ptr = std::begin(members);

printf("val: %i addr: %p\n", ptr->get(), (void*)&ptr->get());
ptr++;
printf("val: %i addr: %p\n", ptr->get(), (void*)&ptr->get());
```

P.S. I took the liberty of fixing the `printf` call. `%x` is wrong for a pointer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think I've quite understood what you're trying to achieve, but...

If you're sure that `sizeof(test1uni) == sizeof(test2uni) == sizeof(int)` and there's nothing else in the struct, then you can treat `finalstruct` itself as an array of `int`s:

```
int *ptr = (int*)&finstr;
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(finstr)/sizeof(int); i++)
    printf("val: %i addr: %x\n", ptr[i], &ptr[i]);
```

But as raised in the comments, casting the struct to an int probably violates strict aliasing, and "type-punning" using the members of union is no longer explicitly allowed in C++ (as opposed to explicitly not allowed). Thus this is in the realm of undefined behaviour, so you need to either:

1. Disable optimisations based on strict aliasing. Eg. pass `-fno-strict-aliasing` to GCC 3.4.1 and above. Still have the type-punning issue though.
2. Check the assembly to make sure the compiler is doing what you want.
3. Change to C.

Also be aware of other gotchas: `int` has to be a multiple of a word, `finstr` has to be aligned to a word boundary, the compiler/platform has to follow convention. So I certainly wouldn't consider this portable without a fair bit more rigour.

Comment: This will be used only on one type of processor, compiled with one compiller (gcc) and all sizes that you've mentioned will be equal. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to change different bits easily by using struct, and for reading I need to know only what will be final value that these bits will make, and for that I will use union. By packing these unions inside struct, I can easily process data.

Comment: This is UB on any compiler, on any processor, on any day.

Comment: Please elaborate on the source of the UB. Beyond the alignment caveats I mentioned, I believe this to be defined behaviour. Perhaps you have a counter-example? From C99 §6.7.2.1: "Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa. There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning."

Comment: (a) This question is tagged C++, not C. (b) As I said to the OP, computer programming is about more than layout in memory. You have aliasing to consider. You're pretending that a `finalstruct` is an array of `int`s; it is not. The type system is a real thing, not just a make-believe veneer! There _are_ some exceptions to this rule where things are more relaxed: if this is one of those times, you should cite the relevant passage from the C++ standard to prove that this usually-UB approach is appropriate here.

Comment: Types are a make-believe veneer, designed to make the programmer's job easier. C99 is a normative reference for C++11. In fact §3.9 of C++11 has footnote: "The intent is that the [C++] memory model is compatible with that of [C99]". But you're right, this might be UB in C++ for two reasons: strict aliasing (§3.10 of C++11 is notoriously ambiguous) and union type punning (§9.5 of C++11 says only one member of a union can be "active" at a time). When behaviour is not explicitly defined, it's UB, so: check the assembly to make sure; pass `-fno-strict-aliasing` to GCC 3.4.1; switch to C.